# How to pass data from activity to a class?

Tags: java, android, class, oop, android-activity

How can i send data from an activity to a class ?

I tried to pass a String using getter but this gives me the initial value of the variable , but my String's value changes in my onCreate. Any ideas how can i pass it to my class ?

Here is some code :

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private String global ; 
    public String getGlobal() {
    return global;
}
 ...
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    ...
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            global = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

        }
    });
}
```

And here is my class

```
public class SimpleVar {
MainActivity mainActivity = new MainActivity() ;
String data = mainActivity.getGlobal; }
```

Any help will be much appreciated. Thank you in advance !

Comment: Activity instance that runs in android OS and the object inside SimpleVar class are different. Not sure what exactly you are trying to do. But this is very wrong and off the track of android development

Comment: `you need to pass the context` and use that `context` in `SimpleVar` to access `getGlobal()`

Comment: Please show a [mcve] of how you would use `SimpleVar.data` assuming this worked.

Answer (score 2):

`global` is not actually "global"

Each instance of the Activity has its own string, and the OS can decide to kill your Activity at any time and recreate it, so therefore don't rely on a variable from an Activity within another class.

Secondly, never ever make a `new` Activity. That is no longer tied to the Activity that you would eventually click the button on.

It's hard to determine what you really need, but this is more correct.

```
public class SimpleVar {
    String data; 
}
```

With the Activity sending data to it

```
private SimpleVar var;
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); 
    ...
    var = new SimpleVar();
   listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            var.data = String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position));

       }
    });
}
```

If you need that object elsewhere, you need to pass it around to those classes from this Activity

Answer (score 1):

try to make constructor for your class

```
public class  SimpleVar {
private String data;

public SimpleVar(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}
```

}

then in your activity new the class and then set data to it

Answer (score 0):

You should not create new mainactivity in your class.
When on instantiating the class pass to it a reference to Activity in which the class was created. Reference to Activity should be kept in a weakreference. Then You can make a getter in the Activity and call it from Your class.

Or You can do the opposite - keep reference to the instantiated object in the Activity. Use setter from the activity to pass new values to the object.

Comment: Keeping references to Activities is typically a memory leak

Comment: Thanx, should use weakreference for that